Fish shell on Cygwin: Infinite loop of errors on startup
I switched to fish, version 3.5.x, on Cygwin (on Windows) and was really enjoying it.
Then I realized that I wanted the updated 'abbr' features from version 3.7.1 of fish, and so I updated my Cygwin fish.
Now, whenever I start fish (inside of MS Terminal) I get an infinite loop that repeats the following error(s):
warning: An error occurred while redirecting file 'C:\MIkesStuff\Pers\Dropbox\Personal\home/fish/fish_variables.lock'
warning: Path 'C:\MIkesStuff\Pers\Dropbox\Personal\home/fish/fish_variables.lock' does not exist
warning: An error occurred while redirecting file 'C:\MIkesStuff\Pers\Dropbox\Personal\home/fish/fish_variables.lock'
warning: Path 'C:\MIkesStuff\Pers\Dropbox\Personal\home/fish/fish_variables.lock' does not exist
warning: An error occurred while redirecting file 'C:\MIkesStuff\Pers\Dropbox\Personal\home/fish/fish_variables.lock'
warning: Path 'C:\MIkesStuff\Pers\Dropbox\Personal\home/fish/fish_variables.lock' does not exist

Often (but not always) I can press Ctrl+C to break the loop and have it return to the normal, interactive shell that I'm expecting.
If anyone has any ideas about how to fix this that would be greatly appreciated
but
I'm guessing that this is a pretty obscure problem.  If anyone has any advice on how to debug this issue that would be perfect.
Stuff I've tried so far:

I deleted the fish_variables.lock file (and the fish_variables file) in the hopes that the shell would recreate it.  Restarting the shell causes the fish_variables file to get recreated but I keep seeing the above infinite loop of errors about fish_variables.lock
I created a fish_variables file in the right place.  It's a text file with 0777 permissions in Cygwin.  I still see the same error
I read about the fish --debug='<list goes here>' startup option, along with fish --print-debug-categories.  I'm either not getting useful info (i.e., no relevant messages and then the infinite loop starts) or I'm getting an overwhelming amount of irrelevant messages (the AST option, and the proc options).
I tried renaming my config dir (so as to hide my config.fish file) and the error still happened.
I put my config.fish back, put an echo statement as the very first line, and the infinite loop happened before my config.fish's echo statement.  I had to press Ctrl+C and then my echo statement happened.
I tried changing my HOME env var in Windows (so that it was the Cygwin/Unix equivalent - I copy-and-pasted the result of cygpath -U "C:\...." - closed and restarted MS Terminal, and fish was still showing the same error (with the mixed Windows + unix path)

I'm at a loss for what to try next.  One thought is that maybe there's a problem with the path, specifically that it's part Windows-style ("C:\MIkesStuff\Pers\Dropbox\Personal\home") and part Unix-style ("/fish/fish_variables.lock") but I'm not sure where to even start looking for where that path is constructed.
Again, any help or advice on what to look at to troubleshoot/debug this would be most appreciated!
Thanks!
--Mike

The goofy Windows path was coming from the XDG_CONFIG_HOME env var.  Deleting that means that fish can start up ok.
